# Ptrace prevents signal from interrupting pselect() in traced process

Tags: linux, unix, select, signals, ptrace

I'm trying to monitor syscalls for a binary using ptrace. The binary sleeps in pselect() and without ptrace, a SIGQUIT makes it return from pselect. The mask of blocked signals passed to pselect includes SIGQUIT.

When executed with ptrace, it exits from sys_pselect6 but not all the way out of glibc's pselect. What am I doing that prevents sys_pselect6 from exiting out to user code ?

Tracer:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid = fork(), sys_in = 1, status;

    if (pid == 0) {
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, getppid(), NULL, NULL) < 0)
            err(1, "TRACEME()");

        execl("./child", "./child", NULL);
        err(1, "execl()");
    }

    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid) err(1, "wait()");

    for (;; sys_in ^= 1) {
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL) < 0) err(1, "SYSCALL");

        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid) err(1, "wait()");

        if (sys_in) {
            long long sys_no = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, 8 * ORIG_RAX, NULL);
            printf("syscall entry %lld\n", sys_no);
        }
        else printf("syscall exit\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Child:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <err.h>

void handle_sigquit(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void *ctx)
{
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigset_t orig_mask;
    struct sigaction sa = {};

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handle_sigquit;
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, NULL);

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask) < 0) err(1, "sigprocmask()");

    pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &orig_mask);
    warn("pselect()");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL)
```

Whenever your debugger gets a notification, you just assume that that notification is about a system call, and handle it accordingly. That is not the case.

Some of the notifications you receive using `wait` are for **signals** that your debugee has received. When those happen, the last NULL in your `PTRACE_SYSCALL` call eliminates, effectively masks, the signal from arriving at the debugee process.

When processing `ptrace` results, you need to check the signal that caused your debugger to wake up. At the very least, check if it's a `SIGTRAP` or something else. If it is something else, the best bet is to pass it on to the debugee process.

Check out this [small program](https://sourceforge.net/p/fakerootng/source/ci/multithreaded_debugger/tree/tests/wait_interrupt.c) to see a simple way of doing it.